# document.body.innerHTML only returns the last case

Tags: javascript

What is the problem with my code? I am trying to get it to return true/false (if has age equal to 27) for all the items, however it only prints the last case, which is true.

How can i get it to print out all of them one after another?

```
var people = [{
    name: "Name1",
    age: 29
}, {
    name: "Name2",
    age: 33
}, {
    name: "Name3"
}, {
    name: "Name4",
    age: 27
}, ];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].age === 27) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
    } else {
        document.body.innerHTML = "False for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmppdn34/1/

Thanks!

Comment: You're replacing the previous content of `document.body` with each round ...

Comment: The contents of body are replaced in your code. `document.body.innerHTML = `. use `document.body.innerHTML += `

Comment: you can use .append() method

Comment: `innerHTML` is a very slow operation. Don't use it at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that only the last person's details are being displayed, instead it's that each of the details are being displayed, but then overwritten by the next iteration of the loop, which is because you're not *appending* content on each iteration, you're *overwriting* on each iteration. Use instead:

```
if(people[i].age === 27) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
    else {
        document.body.innerHTML += "False for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rmppdn34/3/).

If you look at the operators, in your original case you have:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
```

Which, as noted, overwrites the `innerHTML` *each time the loop runs, and the `if` is assessed/executed; whereas I've changed to:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
```

The `+=` appends the new value/output to the the *existing* value

And you could simplify the `if` with a simple ternary, since your output is a Boolean, which would be returned by a simple conditional operator:

```
document.body.innerHTML += (people[i].age === 27) + ' for person number ' + i + '<br />';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rmppdn34/4/).

References:

- [Conditional ('Ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [String operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to append using `+=`:

```
    if(people[i].age === 27) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
    else {
        document.body.innerHTML += "False for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Append instead override ;)

```
 document.body.innerHTML += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
var people = [
    {
    name : "Name1",
    age : 29},
    {
    name : "Name2",
    age : 33},
    {
    name : "Name3"},
    {
    name : "Name4",
    age : 27},
];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    if(people[i].age == 27) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
    else {
        document.body.innerHTML += "False for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
};
```

**output**: False for person number 0
False for person number 1
False for person number 2
True for person number 3

Answer (score 0):

It's because you replace the whole content each iteration. You should generate all the string before putting it in the document because accessing `innerHTML` is a very slow operation.

```
var people = [{
    name: "Name1",
    age: 29
}, {
    name: "Name2",
    age: 33
}, {
    name: "Name3"
}, {
    name: "Name4",
    age: 27
}, ];
var s = "";
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].age === 27) {
        s += "True for person number " + i + "</br>";
    } else {
        s += "False for person number " + i + "</br>";
    }
};
document.body.innerHTML = s;
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that innerHTML is a slow operation.